# Running os.Chown, and escalating privileges

Tags: linux, go, chown

I need to run an os.Chown() on a directory, but I have no idea how to do this safely. I have the user that the binary runs as in sudoers, but since this is an internal function, how would I escalate privileges?

I don't want to shell to find or chown in Linux with a sudo, however, that would work. But is there a better option?

Comment: As long as the user has privileges to perform the action against the directory, as long as you run the program as that user, this should work as expected. os.Chown should operate the same `chown` from the command line.

Comment: @ErkinDjindjiev The problem is, the program is run as a local user while LDAP provides the various groups by which we control access based on user group membership. I see no other solution other than using sudoers to let it execute certain commands, like chown. I could possibly run as an LDAP user who would have membership in various groups so that it can change group ownership. Not sure if I could use setuid/setguid bits on a wrapper script. Worried about creating security holes.

Comment: I think the short answer is no, there is no better option. You can drop privileges easily, but escalating them is hard, for a reason.

Comment: @tripleee I understand and was trying to think of a way to not escalate privileges and still be able to chown based on membership. I'll try adding the local user to all the respective groups and that might work. I'll post later. 

Speaking of privs, how does one drop them?

Comment: If you are root, you can `su` (or in Python `os.setuid()`) to any user you like. Another option might be to write a small `setuid` program which only performs the privileged operation after checking a number of conditions.

Comment: @triplee that sounds good with an entry in sudoers to restrict to execution of said shell script that has been hardened down. Thanks for the suggestions.